# How to select rows in a ndarray based on list condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an ndarray of shape (1, 1, 5, 7) and it looks like this:

```
array[0][0] = 
[[ 0.   5.   0.9  0.6  0.3  0.8  0.7]
 [ 0.   5.   0.5  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.7]
 [ 0.   9.   0.6  0.8  0.4  1.   1. ]
 [ 0.   9.   0.5  0.8  0.3  0.9  0.6]
 [ 0.  16.   0.6  0.1  0.   0.4  0.4]]
```

I would like to select only rows where the value of the second column is either `5` or `9`.

To do that, I created a list `list = [5, 9]` and a function below to check if the second column's value is either those in the `list`:

```
def check(list, array):
    tf_array = np.zeros(np.shape(array))
    for l in list:
        for i, element in enumerate(array):
            if element == l:
                tf_array[i] = True
    return tf_array
```

Then I used `np.compress(check(list, array[0, 0, :, 1]), array, axis=2)` to extract rows that have the second column's value being either of those in the list.

**However, I feel like there has to be a simpler way! Sorry as I am quite new to Numpy so please can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!**

*Edit*

Thanks for your answers! Sorry that I forgot to mention the list is generic and I want to be able to specify it. And I suddenly remeber that one can use the condition `not in` combined with `np.where` and `np.delete` so my problem is solved now!

Comment: Try `array[:, 2] == 5 | array[:, 2] == 9`, or check [np.isin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

Comment: You show `array[0,0]`.  What does `array[0,0,:,1]` look like?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change your array to 2-dimension, try this:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[ 0,   5,  0.9, 0.6,  0.3,  0.8,  0.7],
 [ 0,   5,   0.5, 0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.7],
 [ 0,   9,   0.6,  0.8,  0.4,  1,   1 ],
 [ 0,   9,   0.5,  0.8,  0.3,  0.9,  0.6],
 [ 0,  16,   0.6,  0.1,  0,   0.4,  0.4]])

for l in a:
    if l[1]==5 or l[1]==9:
        print(l)
```